# How to use an 'if' statement before redirecting to a link in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I have this defined in a model called `analysis_result.rb`:

```
  def total_matches
    return 0 unless self.patterns
    self.patterns.sum do |_, v|
      matches = v.matches.try(:count) || 0
      if v.additional.present? && v.additional['ggroup'].present?
        bc_matches = v.additional['ggroup'].try(:count) || 0
      else
        bc_matches = 0
      end

      matches + bc_matches
    end
  end
```

I am trying to use it in in a view called `_rable_row.haml` in order to check beforehand if  `total_matches` is 0 or not. If it is 0 I want to display a partial instead of letting the user go to the link.

This is  the code from the view to check `if analysis.results.total_matches != 0`:

```
%tr.form-table__row{ class: ('form-table__row--disabled' if analysis.processing?) }
  %td.form-table__data= check_box_tag "checkbox_object_ids[]", analysis.id

  %td.form-table__data
    - if analysis.results.total_matches == 0
      = render partial: 'partials/shared/empty'
    - elsif analysis.results.total_matches != 0
      = link_to analysis.title, analysis, class: 'js-toggle', data: { href: "loading-#{analysis.id}" }

    - unless analysis.viewed
      %span.dashboard__icon.dashboard__icon--small.fa.fa-circle.text-info{ aria: { hidden: 'true' }, title: 'New' }
```

I get `undefined method 'total_matches' for #<Mongoid::Criteria:0x00007fc51c5e3720>`

Comment: What is `analysis.results` ? Is an instance of `AnalysisResult` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem differently:

```
- if analysis.results.sum(&:total_matches) != 0
```

only changed to this.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem comes from the definition of the method itself. You've declared your method `total_matches` on `analysis_result.rb` but you're calling `analysis.results.total_matches`. 
I would write `analysis.total_matches`.

Bonus:

I would suggest a guard clause on top of your method `total_matches`

```rb
def total_matches
  return 0 unless self.patterns
  # ...
end
```

Comment: I tried also `result.total_matches` because that's how I use it in another view, but it's still giving me NameError: at analysis 
undefined local variable or method `result' for #

Comment: Can you add you analysis service?

Comment: Do you mean the analysis model?

Comment: `analysis_result.rb`

Comment: I added another part from analysis_result.rb, but not the entire model as it is quite long and not related to this I guess.

Comment: Thanks. Can you add the complete error message? + code part about `analysis.results` (should be the model `Analysis` with attributes or relationship `results`).

Comment: Okay, you can check it out in my initial post. Thanks!

Comment: Ok! Somehow, `analysis.results` is not returning an `ActiveRecord::Relation` but `Mongoid::Criteria`. Do you have an instance method named `results` on `analysis.rb` or in any of your included concerns?

Answer (score 0):

From what I could see in your updated question, your AnalysisResult belongs to Analysis. and total_matches is a instance method of Analysis.

But you are calling it like analysis.results.total_matches here, analysis.results will give you an active record array as analysis has_many results, on top of which you are trying to call total_matches.

You should try analysis.results.find the one instance and call total_matches on top of it.

For ex: analysis.results.last.total_matches(I am just taking .last for example)

Comment: if called like that `analysis.total_matches` I get `the undefined method 'total_matches' for #<Analysis:`

Comment: @luftgekuhltlover From what I could see in your updated question, your AnalysisResult belongs to Analysis. and total_matches is a instance method of Analysis.

But you are calling it like analysis.results.total_matches

here,  analysis.results will give you an active record array as analysis has_many results, on top of which you are trying to call total_matches. 

You should try analysis.results.find the one instance and call total_matches on top of it.

For ex: analysis.results.last.total_matches(I am just taking .last for example)

Comment: @luftgekuhltlover , please mark the answer correct in that case.  thank you :)